# Intermittently getting exception "org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection" on Google app engine

Tags: java, hibernate, google-app-engine, jpa, jdbc

I am using Google App engine, CloudSQL and Hibernate in my project. For last few days I am getting an exception "org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection" for some time and it goes away after some time.
Error log shows the error happens for roughly 50% of my API calls

Have checked the hibernate configuration and seems to be right
This has become a major issue now. Any help is appreciated.

```
<property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>     
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:google:mysql://<my cloud SLQ instance>/<mydb></property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">xxxx</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxx</property>
<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
<property name='connection.pool_size'>1</property> 
<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name='hibernate.dialect'>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name='show_sql'>false</property>  
<!-- Drop and re create schema -->
<property name='hbm2ddl.auto'>update</property>
```

Here is the exception log

```
  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
W 13:31:43.908 /productList
  org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1854)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1831)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2111)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3917)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1091)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2473)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:987)
    at com.shimplify.core.DaoUtil.getById(DaoUtil.java:38)
    at com.shimplify.core.DaoUtil.getById(DaoUtil.java:30)
    at com.shimplify.servlet.ProductList.doGet(ProductList.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:482)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:234)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:46)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:350)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2450)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2235)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:818)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor34.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:46)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleNonRegisteringDriver$JdbcWrapper.getInstance(GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.java:276)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.connect(GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
  <continued in next message>
W 13:31:43.908 <continued from previous message>
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1854)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1831)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2111)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3917)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1091)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2473)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:987)
    at com.shimplify.core.DaoUtil.getById(DaoUtil.java:38)
    at com.shimplify.core.DaoUtil.getById(DaoUtil.java:30)
    at com.shimplify.servlet.ProductList.doGet(ProductList.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    ... 1 more
  Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unable to open connection to the instance: boxnsights:boxnsightsdb
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleCloudSqlSocket.<init>(GoogleCloudSqlSocket.java:48)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleCloudSqlSocketFactory.connect(GoogleCloudSqlSocketFactory.java:81)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    ... 67 more
  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /cloudsql/boxnsights:boxnsightsdb (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:259)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:136)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleCloudSqlSocket$RandomAccessFileHelper.getFile(GoogleCloudSqlSocket.java:249)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleCloudSqlSocket.<init>(GoogleCloudSqlSocket.java:46)
    ... 69 more
F 13:31:43.914 Uncaught exception from servlet
  org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1854)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1831)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2111)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3917)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1091)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2473)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:987)
    at com.shimplify.core.DaoUtil.getById(DaoUtil.java:38)
    at com.shimplify.core.DaoUtil.getById(DaoUtil.java:30)
    at com.shimplify.servlet.ProductList.doGet(ProductList.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:482)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:234)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:46)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:350)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2450)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2235)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:818)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor34.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:46)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleNonRegisteringDriver$JdbcWrapper.getInstance(GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.java:276)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.connect(GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPrep...(length 13134)
```

Comment: I am not using EntityManager instead using SessionFactory

Comment: My base class looks something like this

public abstract class BaseClass {
 private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
 
 private Session session;
 //initialize the sessionFactory only once
 static{  
  Configuration configuration =  new Configuration().configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
  configuration.setInterceptor(new BaseDaoInterceptor());
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
  System.out.println("Session Factory created");
 }

Comment: Then I use sessionFactory.openSession(); to get a session and session.saveOrUpdate(); to save the objects

Comment: Thanks Andrei, looks like that is the issue, I am not closing the session in some cases. Will correct the same and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is solved after I started using

```
ServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.buildServiceRegistry());
```

Previously I was using the deprecated method(below) which seemed to work for limited time be then started giving errors for around 50% calls.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```

I am using hibernate 4.2 so have not used StandardServiceRegistryBuilder

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, you do not ALWAYS [`close`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#close%28%29)/disconnect Hiberante's Session. To make sure it always happen, no matter what exception are thrown, you could execute your code in a `try/finally` block, otherwise the connection is not returned to the JDBC pool (where you have a bounded number of connections).

In case you use the JPA API, you should call the [`EntityManager.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#close--) method.

Comment: I am glad I could help. Sometimes the exact place where the connection "escapes" is complicated to find. That's why it is better to write the code from the very beginning with that in mind.

Comment: Unfortunately getting errors again from today morning.

Comment: The issue gets resolved when I redeploy the application on Google App engine.

Comment: @KetanKale you probably have a scheduler or a service that you executed seldom and that consumes JDBC connections without returning them. That the issue got resolved when deploying on Google App, does not mean the problem is not there.

Comment: that was my initial assumption as well and hence I disabled the Task queue completely but it did not solve the problem.  Currently I have change the build session factory to accept ServiceRegistry sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.buildServiceRegistry()); Previously I was using  depricated method sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

Comment: currently not getting errors but decided to wait for a day before reaching a conclusion and posting here

Comment: tried to upvote but I am new to Stack so they dont allow me to upvote till i accumulate 15 points :( And yes I have a local db and tried with commenting the if condition for environment check and just use the production configuration but with not much luck. Using ServiceRegistryBuilder surely helped hence have added that as the answer.